# How to host multiple SSL sites on a single Host in IIS 7

Tags: iis, ssl, https, ca

I am having some trouble with hosing.
Currently on our server have have 6 or so IIS sites hosted. They are all http currently: and work on port 80 with the host names set.

Now I want to go an change them to use SSL. But this then removes the ability to use the Host headers.

I have tried using self generated ssl cert from within IIS Manager before I go out and buy real ones. But the issue I am having is that it seems that the SSL cert is linked to an IP address. I can add the ssl cert to one site. But after that When I try assign site 2. it says that there are no Ip addresses.

So My question which Im hoping someone can explain how it works when multiple sites are hosted with iis on the same machine.

Do I have to get a wildcard SSL Certificate?
Do I need to have a unique IP address for each site being hosted?

If not, could somebosy please help and try explain to me what I need to do in order to achieve this.

Comment: When switching to SSL, the server needs to direct things to the correct IIS virtual domain during the SSL handshake (and not during the HTTP request via the `Host` header). You can do that with [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), which is a TLS feature (and not SSL feature). Unfortunately, you need [IIS 8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2012/09/04/server-name-indication-sni-in-iis-8-windows-server-2012.aspx) to utilize SNI. Once the server is SNI capable, then you have to worry about clients you don't control. Old clients and SSLv3 clients will be a problem.

Comment: So are you saying, that I cant run multiple sites in IIS 7 with ssl ?

Comment: Your question is off-topic here, as it's not about programming.